# why am I getting error initiating class instance in a servlet running in tomcat?

Tags: java, class, tomcat, servlets, web

I've checked multiple times but cant figure out why ,I am trying to run a simple servlet that returns the time ...please help

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1"
    metadata-complete="true">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ts</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>TS</servlet-class>

    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ts</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ts</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**TS.java**

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TS extends HttpServlet
{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException    
    {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today=new java.util.Date();

        out.println(
        "<html>"+
        "<body>"+
        "<h1 align=center>  Date  is</h1> "+
        "<br>"+
        today+
        "</body>"+
        "</html>"
        );

    }//get ends
}//class ends
```

I placed the WEB-INF and classes folders in time and the time directory is  under webapps , and I am calling the url as localhost:8080/time/ts

**Error says this**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class TS

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class TS

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class TS
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TS
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image: File Tree]

Comment: Don't, ever, put any class in the default package. Show us the recursive contents of your webapp directory.

Comment: I don't get it , can you please explain in detail?

Comment: See the Java tutorial about packages. This is basic stuff that you should learn before servlets.

Comment: No no I asked what you meant by recursive contents is webapps?

Comment: Show us the file tree that you have in the directory of your deployed web application.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited the post , go check

Comment: The classes directory must be **inside** WEB-INF. Not next to WEB-INF.

Comment: Thank you so much , silly me :P ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes directory must be inside WEB-INF not along with it as mentioned by @JB Nizet in the comments

Answer (score -2):

You should specify the full path to the servlet class in web.xml.

```
<servlet-class>xxx.yy.z.TS</servlet-class>
```